# Bluetooth connectivity disconnects ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: sound, bluetooth, connection

When I connect the Bluetooth headphones with the computer is successfully connected, but when I turn on a voice multimedia the connection is disconnected and the audio comes out with the headphones of the device, what can I do?

Comment: What is "a voice broker"? And what is "the device"?

Comment: Still the question is not clear. What is the BT device? Are you loading music by Wi-Fi at the same time. What do you mean by "audio comes out with the headphones of the device"?